# Rails Render Customization

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a Web Designer who is currently handling the implementation of my design to a Rails web App.

I'm currently having a problem on this code.

```
<%= render 'letterhead_link' %>
```

It currently outputs:

```
<a href="/letterheads/2/edit">Edit Letterhead</a>
```

I am assuming that the "Edit Letterhead" link changes to create, if ever the user doesn't have a Letterhead yet, since there can only be one letterhead per user.

I tried searching in the controller for this "letterhead_link", but I couldn't find anything.

So, I'm not sure, but is there any way I can customize that to have an output like this?

```
<a href="/letterheads/2/edit" class="letterhead"><span class="icon"></span>Letterhead</a>
```

I do need the extra tags to incorporate an icon with the link.
I hope someone here can help me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the 
`<%= render 'letterhead_link' %>`
 gives the output like this

`<a href="/letterheads/2/edit">Edit Letterhead</a>`

Then, Try the following to get what you like to need,

```
<%= render 'letterhead_link', class: 'letterhead' do %>
  <span class="icon"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but this just renders a template so you should look for 'letterhead_link' in your views folder (the filename might be with '_' in the beginning). I bet that the hyperlink is built in there and you should change it there.